# how to send push notification using yammer api

Tags: ios, yammer

I am planning to use Yammer APIs to develop an App that will assign task to other members with in a group. Can we send push notification from one device to another device while assigning task to other member using Yammer APIs?

Comment: please add minimum solution you tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs provided for generating specific notifications to end users. Yammer puts users in control of notifications they receive so you should just post a message to a group with the available APIs, and if the user has notifications enabled, then they may receive notifications.